# UINavigationController: wrong position for ChildViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

For building an App having a customized TabBarController where the Tabs are at the top of the screen, i use the [MHTabBarController](https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController).

But I changed the [MHTabBarController in that way](https://github.com/itinance/MHTabBarController), that the Base Controller is not UIViewController, but a UINavigationController because i need push segues and all that stuff which needs UINavigationController.

The Problem is: the last Tab (the ViewController of the last tab) is rendered on a wrong vertical position. The ViewController starts more pixel below than the other ones.

The [code is on github](https://github.com/itinance/MHTabBarController).

Some Screenshots showing the issue:

**Tab 1 (okay as expected):**

[image]

**Tab 2 (Okay as expected):**

[image]

**Tab 3 (Not okay, it starts under the expected position):**

[image]

What could be the root cause? Switching from UINavigationController to UIViewController solves the issue.

Comment: Try entering the following: `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`

Comment: Yes, it solved the issue! Thanks a lot !

   https://github.com/itinance/MHTabBarController/commit/90952d2fd028f22e10708bfdc2c2271545e8b09c

You should post the answer that i can mark it as "solved"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either fix it programmatically like so:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Or you can do it in the storyboard like this:

Go to the attributes inspector of the View Controller by selecting the xib or the controller in Storyboard. Uncheck the **Adjust Scroll View Insets** in **Layout**.

[image]